# Weird behavior when writing and reading file

Tags: python, python-2.7

When executing the following code, after the second read, file gets filled with zero until being 4096 bytes large. I can't figure out why :

```
f = open("file.txt", "w+")
f.read()
# gives ''
f.write("Hello")
f.read()
# filled with \x00,\x00
f.close()
# file is 4096 bytes large...
```

Comment: How do you measure the size of the file?

Comment: Fabian : I do it with my OS
Blender : same result with an empty file and r+ (I use w+ in the example to create the file if not present)

Comment: I didn't get the result on my machine, what's your platform?

Comment: I think your can't `read()` after `write()` without a [`flush()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) in between.

Comment: Which OS? Same as Marcus, I can't reproduce this on Linux, x86-64.

Comment: Marcus : i'm on Win7, python 2.7, IDLE

Comment: Paolo, it's true that if i'm doing this, i don't get this behavior anymore... Still weird though, any pointer on the fact that you can't read after write ?

Comment: Just tried on my Fedora, no problemo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to solve your problem: don't mix `read()` and `write()`.

Otherwise: after the `write()`, use `seek()` before the second `read()` to read your file *from the beginning*:

```
f = open("file.txt", "w+")
print f.read()      # prints ''
f.write("Hello")
f.seek(0)
print f.read()      # print 'Hello'
f.close()
```

Comment: @PaoloMoretti True. Also note that the behaviour of the OPs code depends on the OS/filesystem you use. While the code would probably work on Linux with Ext3/Ext4, using it on Win7 with NTFS will result in a bunch of garbage written to the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to the filesystem and/or partition.  I'm not fully up to speed on the details, but it is likely that 4096 bytes (i.e. exactly 4Kb) is the minimum size of a file in your filesystem and partition.  AFAIK, the partition has a block size (often 4096 bytes), and files can only be allocated to whole blocks.  So a file is always a multiple of 4096 bytes.  I think that some filesystems have a way around this (e.g. reiserfs) by combining small files.