# Unexpected file behavior python

Tags: python, file, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird behavior when writing and reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083183/weird-behavior-when-writing-and-reading-file)

When I try to write into a file and then read it, I get an unexpected result.

My code is:

```
f=open("z.txt","w+")
f.write("Hello")
content=f.read()
print content
f.close()
```

The outputted file is:

> Hellolף      ן  (I11 (S'QUEUE' p1 (S'exec' p2 S'runcode' p3
>   (cidlelib.rpc unpickle_code p4
>   (S'c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00s6\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00d\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x83\x02\x00Z\x01\x00e\x01\x00j\x02\x00d\x02\x00\x83\x01\x00\x01e\x01\x00j\x03\x00\x83\x00\x00Z\x04\x00e\x01\x00j\x05\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01d\x03\x00S(\x04\x00\x00\x00s\x05\x00\x00\x00z.txts\x02\x00\x00\x00w+t\x05\x00\x00\x00HelloN(\x06\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00opent\x01\x00\x00\x00ft\x05\x00\x00\x00writet\x04\x00\x00\x00readt\x07\x00\x00\x00contentt\x05\x00\x00\x00close(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x17\x00\x00\x00C:/Users/x/Desktop/zt\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x01\r\x01\x0c\x01'
>   tRp5 tp6 (dp7 ttp8 tp9 .  ‘2ר ְ ז׀l      Ak       !
>   €qg   ¸Ck   PCk   $      ְBkאBkנBk                 8Ck
>            xCk    XBkxBk                    °Ck׀CkנCkDk
>      @‘   (Ck˜Ck              kצ    Ck Ck
>   ְpg    DkDֽ˜F   !      €qg                +      ˜Ck
>              (Dk
>       @k @k               xDk   ר?k   @f                            HDkhDkpDk                   ˜Dk
>   נDkEk0EkPEk       ְ”                          kצ
>         ְpg                   !      ˜F                   ,
>   ״Dk
>
> ```
> @k @k                      ר?k
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, your `.read()` will have returned an empty string, since the write put the file position at the end. Secondly, the `w+` mode would have truncated the file, causing the file to be empty when you opened it. The extra data you see was added *after* this program was run. What else have you done with this file? Nothing in your code shown would have added the extra data, but the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) output looks a lot like what you pasted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a Windows issue, to do with filesystem block sizes. If you `.flush()` the `.write()` before you `.read()`, it will work fine. I can reproduce it on Win7.

(I think what is happening is that Windows allocates your file in blocks of 4KB, so writing `"Hello"` bumps you up to the next block size. If you then `.read()` you get random gibberish from the rest of the block, because Python hasn't had a chance to deal with it yet. If you `.flush()` before `.read()`ing, Python writes out the file properly and then you just get an empty string.)

Comment: So in fact it's a bug on python's memory handling?

Comment: @user1718294 It's not a bug. Python `file.read()` is simply a wrapper for the underlying `fread()` C function, and [C standards](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2230732/63011) says you should always flush (or seek) your stream to get the correct result.

Comment: I wonder whether it is sensible to automatically flush a file that has been written before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open("z.txt","w+")
f.write("Hello")
f.seek(0)
content=f.read()
print content
f.close()
```

I was missing
 `f.seek(0)`

Comment: That doesn't explain your extra pickle data, but if this answers your question..

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes, it solved my problem, now the file also contains the text "Hello" and not the other gibberish stuff.

Comment: So where did the gibberish come from? It still seems a mystery; it shouldn't have been there at all.

Comment: @Will Vousden That's why I asked the question in the first place, I had no idea where did the gibberish came from.